How can I apply security updates to the git client that comes with Xcode?
I am looking at how to upgrade my git client that comes with Xcode command line tools in the light of the recent vulnerability announcement.
Is this possible?

You can install a newer version of git, if you want. Many people use Homebrew or MacPorts to do this.

Why do you want a later version?  (I'm a casual git user, and have never noticed any problems with the built-in version, but you've made me curious…)

https://github.blog/2024-05-14-securing-git-addressing-5-new-vulnerabilities/

Which versions of macOS, Xcode and git are you currently using?

No, install git from MacPorts or Homebrew and use it instead of the packaged version from Apple when you need to react to security updates faster than Apple ships them.

This doesn't answer the question being asked.

I’ve changed that with an edit. Still not great @Allan but it’s clearly an answer even if it’s wrong (or not) to some degree.

How is it wrong or not an answer?  Apple upgrades the git they ship when they put out a new Xcode, not otherwise.  So if it needs to be updated out-of-band, your choices are build it yourself, or use some of the packaging solutions, the most common being Homebrew or MacPorts.  The edit from @bmike does make it better.

I voted it as right, some people will interpret the question super strictly and say you need to answer how to get Apple to fix the other binary. This is practical, secure and well documented +1 but everyone gets a vote. It could be better based the question better IMO as well. It's very good to address what was asked and also be generally useful.
